# SMTP Email Send Issue by using PHPMailer

Tags: visual-studio, smtp, office365, phpmailer, .net-4.8

I am New here .I am facing recently Email Send issue  from my Windows server. 50% cases mail are unable to send  User.
Below Error message are showing

```
*******Password not accepted from server: 421 4.7.66 TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are not supported. Please upgrade/update your client to support TLS 1.2. Visit https://aka.ms/smtp_auth_tls. [SI2P153CA0009.APCP153.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]******* 

This is my Mail Server Configuration code :

<?php
//require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
//date_default_timezone_set('PRC'); //Set China time zone 
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dhaka');
$mail = new PHPMailer(); //Instantiate
$mail->SetLanguage("en", 'language.php');
$mail->SMTPDebug = 4; 
$mail->SetLanguage("en");
$mail->IsSMTP(); //  Enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;  //Enable SMTP authentications
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';  
$mail->Host = "Smtp.office365.com"; //SMTP server Take 163 mailbox as an example
$mail->Port = 587;  //Mail sending port
$mail->Username = "UserName";  //your mailbox
$mail->Password = "Password";  //Your password

?>
```

I have install Visual studio 2022 for upgrading .NET framework .
Can you please Tell me how can I solved issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should always do when presented with an error message is to **read it**:

```
TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are not supported. Please upgrade/update your client to support TLS 1.2. Visit https://aka.ms/smtp_auth_tls
```

This suggests that your server, or at least the PHP version you are running on it, is badly outdated. On top of that, I can see that you are using a very old and unsupported version of PHPMailer, so [upgrade](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: Thanks Brother ,I have Updated my code and it's working now perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it .I updated my code and Using Latest PHPMailler version .getting 100% mail right now .Below code works for me ..

```
<?php

require 'includes/PHPMailer.php';
require 'includes/SMTP.php';
require 'includes/Exception.php';

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

$mail = new PHPMailer(); //Instantiate
$mail->isSMTP(); //  Enable SMTP
$mail->Host = "Smtp.office365.com"; //SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = "true";  //Enable SMTP authentications
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; 
$mail->Port = "587";  //Mail sending port
$mail->Username = "Username";  //your mailbox
$mail->Password = "Password";  //Your
```

?>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).